# Divide chocolate bar with if/elif/else

Tags: python, if-statement

I've been having problem with this simple question. was able to solve it with **for** loop, but not only **if/elif/else**. Any suggestion on how to tackle this?

Question:

> Chocolate bar has the form of a rectangle divided into n×m portions.
>   Chocolate bar can be split into two rectangular parts by breaking it
>   along a selected straight line on its pattern. Determine whether it is
>   possible to split it so that one of the parts will have exactly k
>   squares. The program reads three integers: n, m, and k. It should
>   print YES or NO.

my if solution, but when the input is (4,2,6), the answer is incorrect.

```
n = int(input())
m = int(input())
k = int(input())

if k/max(n,m) % 1 == 0 and k/max(n,m) <= min(n,m):
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Comment: `k/max(n,m) % 1` is always 0...

Comment: What's wrong with using a for loop? Also, what other resources do you have available? For example, can you use a routine that returns the prime factorization of `k`?

Comment: it's not very clear what other resources is available.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i want to make sure it doesn't return float

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the question is basically asking:

> For a given n, m and k, does there exist two numbers, a and b, such that a * b = k, where either a = n and b < m or a = m and b < n.

You can solve that with this condition:

```
n = int(input())
m = int(input())
k = int(input())

if (k % n == 0 and k / n < m) or (k % m == 0 and k / m < n):
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

The thing you are forgetting is that it can be cut from top-to-bottom *or* left-to-right.

Comment: Was about to post the exact same code but with an `elif` for the two cases. It might be worth noting that using `<` rather than `<=` enforces the condition that the bar actually needs to be broken (i.e. k=n*m prints "NO").

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int m = scanner.nextInt();
        int k = scanner.nextInt();

        if(((k % n == 0) && (k/n < m)) || ((k % m == 0) && (k/m < n))) {
            System.out.println("YES");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.